# Lusin's Theorem - Proof Verification (Folland Chap 2, Exercise 44)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral

Conisder Lusin's Theorem (Folland Chap 2 Ex 44):

> If $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is Lebesgue measurable and $\epsilon > 0$, there is a compact subset $E \in  [a,b]$ s.t. $\mu(E^C) < \epsilon$ and $f$ restricted to $E$ is continuous.

To prove this, I basically:

1. Defined $E_k = \{x | x \in [a,b], |f(x)|<k\}$ and $f_k' = f \chi_{E_k}$. Then $f_k' \rightarrow f$ p.w.
2. Approximated each $f_k'$ is a continuous function $f_k$ (one can show each $f_k'$ is $L^1$)
3. $f_k \rightarrow f$ p.w. so in particular, $f_k \rightarrow f$ a.e
4. By Egoroff's Theorem $\exists F \subset [a,b]$ s.t. $\mu(F) < \epsilon$ and $f_k \rightarrow f$ unifomly on $F^c$. Ergo $f$ is continuous on $F^C$

To complete, I think I can get a compact set by finding one inside $F^C$ because $F^C$ is Borel. But I really didn't use compactness in an essential way to obtain the conclusion. Am I missing something?

Comment: The definition of $E_k$ does not seem to be correct. Since $f(x)$ is a complex number, $f(x)<k$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: It should be magnitude of $f(x)$

Comment: See this link https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/spring11/lusin.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Let $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ be Lebesgue measurable and $\epsilon > 0$. By theorem 2.26 we can build a sequence of continuous functions $\{g_n\}$ such that

$$g_n\to f \ \ \text{in} \ \ L^1$$

Then by Corollary 2.32 there is a sub-sequence $\{g_{n_j}\}$ of $\{g_n\}$ such that $g_{n_j}\to f$ almost everywhere. Now by Egoroff's theorem for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a set $F\subset [a,b]$ with $\mu(F) < \epsilon/2$ such that $g_{n_j}\to f$ uniformly on $F^{c}$.

Now by theorem 1.18, since $\mu([a,b]) < \infty$, there is $E$ compact subset of $[a,b]$ such that $E\subset F^c$ and

\begin{align*}
\mu(E^c) &= \mu(F) + \mu(E^c\setminus F)\\
&= \mu(F) + \mu(E^c\cap F^c)\\
&= \mu(F) + \mu(F^c\setminus E)\\
&= \mu(F) + (\mu(F^c) - \mu(E))\\
&\leq \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2\\
&= \epsilon
\end{align*}
Note since $E\subset F^c$ and $g_{n_j}\to f$ uniformly on $F^c$, we have that $g_{n_j}\to f$ uniformly on $E$. Since, for all $j$, $g_{n_j}$ is continuous, we have that $f$ is continuous on $E$, that is, $f|E$ is continuous.

Comment: Theorem 1.18 implies that there is $E$ compact subset of $[a,b]$ such that $E\subset [a,b]$ and $\mu ([a,b]\setminus E) \le \epsilon/2$. May I ask how can we guarantee the existence of such compact set is a subset of $F^c\subset [a,b]$? (I was originally wrote there exists $E$ compact subset of $F^c$...but then I realized that $F^c$ is not necessarily measurable which theorem 1.18 requires.)

Comment: how is $\mu(F^c) - \mu(E)) \leq \epsilon / 2$

Comment: Hi everyone, its been awhile so I need to review before I answer your questions.

Comment: @maskeran I think you can assume $F^c$ is measurable since $f$ is continuous on it, and all continuous functions are measurable.

Comment: @maskeran, $f: F^c \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous, thus it is $(\mathcal{B}_{F^c},\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{C}})-$measurable, thus $f^{-1}(\mathbb{C}) = F^c \in \mathcal{B}_{F^c}$, by Corrollary 2.2, but I also think that by Egoroff's theorem, $F \subset [a,b]$ is assumed to be measurable, thus making $F^c$ measurable, a different version of Egoroff's theorem can be found on page 73 of Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, statement can also be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorov%27s_theorem)